# Rank of matrices and their block form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

My 2 Questions:

Any matrix can be brought into block form however, why does $A$ and $B$ need to have the same rank?

It follows further that Any $m \times n$ matrix is equivalent to the block matrix where the Identity submatrix in the top left is $s \times s$ where $s = \mbox{rank}(A)$. Why is this the case??

My thoughts:

Is it due to the fact that $\mbox{rank} (A)$ the maximum number of linearly independent column/row vectors in the matrix $A$?

What I believe to be the definition- Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices over the field $\Bbb K$. If both $A$ and $B$ have rank $s$, then they can both be brought into the same block (column and row reduced) form.

Say this number were $n$. Then this implies that there are n linearly independent column vectors in $A$. If the rank of $B$ was not $n$, but m then would the size of the identity matrix in the top left of its block form be different?

The block form I am referring to is the following:
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{c|c} 
I_s & 0_{s,n-s} \\ 
\hline 
0_{m-s,s} & 0_{m-s,n-s}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: The statement should be that if they have the same rank, then they can be brought into **the same** block form

Comment: That would make more sense, the text I was referring to didn't specify.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the textbook has some kind of typo

Comment: I still have the same questions however.

Comment: Please try to separate the problem statement from your thoughts about it.